# Postgres: Could not choose a best candidate function

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Can someone explain how to fix this query?

```
SELECT date_part('month', scheduler_scheduleevents.date), sum(price)
    FROM user_settings_userservices
    JOIN scheduler_scheduleevents
    ON scheduler_scheduleevents.service_type_id = user_settings_userservices.id
    WHERE user_settings_userservices.salonid_id = %s
    AND is_start_time = True and is_active = False
    AND ( date < %s or ( date = %s and time < %s ) )
    AND date_part('year', scheduler_scheduleevents.date) = date_part('year', %s)
    GROUP BY date_part('month', scheduler_scheduleevents.date),
    (request.user.id, now_date, now_date, now_time, now_date, )
    )
```

When I try execute this query in django app I get this warning:

```
function date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique

LINE 9: ...ate_part('year', scheduler_scheduleevents.date) = date_part(...
                                                         ^

HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Post the output of `select version()`, and psql's `\d scheduler_scheduleevents`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add an explicit cast:

```
AND date_part('year', scheduler_scheduleevents.date::date) = date_part('year', %s::date)
```

You get this error when postgres can't figure out which actual function execute.

Postgres has the `date_part` function overloaded, it has a version for a *timestamp* as second parameter, and another for an *interval* second parameter: `date_part(text, timestamp)` and `date_part(text, interval)`.

When you say `date_part('year', %s)` postgres doesn't know if it should interprete your `%s` parameter as a *timestamp* or as a *interval*. So it needs you to cast your %s parameter to a type that only matches one of those two versions of the date_part function. When you cast %s to *date*  (i.e. when you write `%s::date`) postgres can only use the first overload of the function, because a *date* can be casted automatically to *timestamp* but can't be casted automatically to *interval*